# Trim/remove first word from a returned list of WordPress posts?

Tags: php

i'm a little inexperienced with PHP, I'm currently building a wordpress site and trying to produce a list of all posts in category, I am currently using..

```
 <?php $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'product',
                    'cat'=> '5');

                    $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

                <?php endwhile; }
                wp_reset_query();?>
```

Which works fine, however I need to remove/trim the first word from the tile of each result (currently a result would come in as "Aluminium Product" where I just want to return "Product")

Ive done a lot of googling and found code examples I have managed to return JUST the first word.. but not the other way round.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use `explode()` to convert your title into array, then use `array_slice()` to remove the first word, finally use `implode()` to join all the words in to result title.

[PHP MANUAL - array_slice()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

[PHP MANUAL - explode()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

[PHP MANUAL - implode()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Second Approach is to use `substr()` and `strpos()`

```
<?php
    $title = "Word1 Word2 Word3";
    $resultTitle = substr($title,strpos($title, ' '));
?>
```

[PHP MANUAL - substr()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

[PHP MANUAL - strpos()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Edited using original code

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

change to

```
<?php 
     $originalTitle = the_title('','',false);
     echo substr($originalTitle,strpos($originalTitle, ' '));
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input ryo.. unfortunatly I'm really not experienced with PHP and am unable to figure out how to use those options.. would you be able to amend the code in my original post?

Comment: I have added the modified code to the last part, please check and let me know if there is any confusion

Comment: Many thanks ryo! worked a charm.. If you don't mind, so I can try and figure it out how it works.. what is actually happening there in the php code? what bit is telling it to remove the first word

Comment: Hi Jon, `substr($originalTitle,strpos($originalTitle, ' '))` is the bit to remove the first word, it's looking for the position of first space, and then return the substring after the first space. cheers